# Postgresql 12 Truncate partition with foreign key

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, constraint

I am building a datawarehouse using Postgresql (12) and think I should be using partitions on the most populated tables, for performance and maintanability reasons.

I have something along the lines of:

```
CREATE TABLE sale (id varchar,
                    vers varchar,
                    CONSTRAINT sale_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id, vers)
                    )
                   PARTITION BY LIST (vers);

CREATE TABLE sale_line (id varchar,
                    sale_id varchar,
                    vers varchar,
                    CONSTRAINT sale_line_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id, vers),
                    CONSTRAINT sale_fk FOREIGN KEY (sale_id, vers) REFERENCES sale(id, vers)
                    )
                   PARTITION BY LIST (vers);

CREATE TABLE sale_v1 PARTITION OF sale FOR VALUES IN ('v1');
CREATE TABLE sale_line_v1 PARTITION OF sale_line FOR VALUES IN ('v1');
CREATE TABLE sale_v2 PARTITION OF sale FOR VALUES IN ('v2');
CREATE TABLE sale_line_v2 PARTITION OF sale_line FOR VALUES IN ('v2');
```

Now, I want to get rid of data in version v2, and I try this:

```
truncate sale_line_v2, sale_v2;
```

and get this error:

```
SQL Error [0A000]: ERROR: cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint
  Détail : Table "sale_line" references "sale_v2".
  Indice : Truncate table "sale_line" at the same time, or use TRUNCATE ... CASCADE.
```

Notice that using 'truncate ... cascade' is not an option. As stated in the documentation (and experimented the hard way), it will also truncate my version v1:

> Note in particular that when the table to be truncated is a partition,
>   siblings partitions are left untouched, but cascading occurs to all
>   referencing tables and **all their partitions** with no distinction.

I ahve seen similar questions on this site ([truncate table with foreign keys](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/218688/truncate-table-with-foreign-keys), [Truncate tables with dependent foreign key constraints](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190073/truncate-tables-with-dependent-foreign-key-constraints)), but no answer working for me. The best approach would be **disabling the constraints**, but this **does NOT work**:

```
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE sale_line disable TRIGGER ALL;
TRUNCATE sale_v2, sale_line_v2;
ALTER TABLE sale_line enable TRIGGER ALL;
COMMIT;
```

results again in:

```
SQL Error [0A000]: ERROR: cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint
  Détail : Table "sale_line" references "sale_v2".
  Indice : Truncate table "sale_line" at the same time, or use TRUNCATE ... CASCADE.
```

I also tried disabling contraints on the partitions I want to truncate in addition to the main table, or even on all partitions and the main table, up to the above, but the result is always the same...

```
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE sale_line disable TRIGGER ALL;
ALTER TABLE sale disable TRIGGER ALL;
ALTER TABLE sale_line_v1 disable TRIGGER ALL;
ALTER TABLE sale_line_v2 disable TRIGGER ALL;
ALTER TABLE sale_v1 disable TRIGGER ALL;
ALTER TABLE sale_v2 disable TRIGGER ALL;
TRUNCATE sale_v2, sale_line_v2;
ALTER TABLE sale_line enable TRIGGER ALL;
ALTER TABLE sale enable TRIGGER ALL;
ALTER TABLE sale_line_v1 enable TRIGGER ALL;
ALTER TABLE sale_line_v2 enable TRIGGER ALL;
ALTER TABLE sale_v1 enable TRIGGER ALL;
ALTER TABLE sale_v2 enable TRIGGER ALL;
COMMIT;

SQL Error [0A000]: ERROR: cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint
  Détail : Table "sale_line" references "sale_v2".
  Indice : Truncate table "sale_line" at the same time, or use TRUNCATE ... CASCADE.
```

So contraints regarding partitions must have some sort of special status... but this defeats the purpose of being able to truncate partitions...

Any hint ?

Comment: Drop and re-create the constraint.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe any idea why disable trigger does not work ?

Comment: The reason is that PostgreSQL first checks if there are *any* triggers (not only enabled ones) on the table, and if yes, it checks `pg_constraint` for foreign key constraints (see `heap_truncate_check_FKs` in `src/backend/catalog/heap.c`).